# Sqlite SELECT * for Last 7 days

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

Im trying to do a SELECT * to retrieve rows for last 7 days in SQLite.

the table structure is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE 'session' ('rowID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 'steps' INTEGER, 'stop_time' DATETIME NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

How do I do this?
Im new at this

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM session WHERE stop_time > (SELECT DATETIME('now', '-7 day'))
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)