# Android sqlite time compare issue

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, timestamp

I am comparing time in android sqlite database, here is my table structure in the screen shots. Actually I have two times, like 8:00 and 7:30 (basically these are employee shift timings) in the string and I have a column `c_TIME` in my database and I want all the records who lies in b/w my two time i.e.(8:00 and 7:30) from c_TIME.

I have used this query but it is not working, please anyone guide me what I am doing wrong

```
SELECT *
FROM ATTENDANCE
WHERE strftime('%H','08:00') > strftime('%H', c_TIME) AND
      time('08:00') < strftime('%H', c_TIME) AND
      STATE = 'IN'
```

[image]

Comment: the above query reruns 0 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM ATTENDANCE
WHERE strftime('%H:%M:%S', c_date) > '07:30:00' AND
      strftime('%H:%M:%S', c_date) < '08:00:00' AND
      STATE = 'IN'
```

**Comments:**

Instead of using the `c_TIME` field, you should use `c_date`.  Actually, I don't see any value in keeping around a column which stores the time separately.

`strftime` returns a string based on some sort of datetime/timestamp input.  The output from `strftime('%H:%M:%S', c_date)` should have the form `HH:MM:SS`, and this *string* can be compared lexicographically against `08:00:00` and `07:30:00`.  The comparison should still work, because for strings of the same length it should still sort numerically.

Comment: this return 0 records

Comment: @Achin Are you certain that you even have any data which should be returned?  The same table in your question has no matching data.

Comment: yes i have 3 values in c_date 2016-11-30 09:18:19  ,   2016-11-25 09:18:19  and 2016-11-26  06:30:00 and this lies b/w '07:30:00' and  '08:00:00'

Comment: No, they don't.  `06:30` is _earlier_ than your desired range, and the 9 am times are _later_ than this range.  Please check your logic.

Comment: actually , i think i have save my time in 12 hr format , is your query work with 24 hr format time?

Comment: Yes, `%H` should be for 24 hour time.

Comment: ok , let me check my logic again ,one thing i want to ask is that should i store my datetime in 24hr format ?

Comment: @Achin If you _don't_ store your datetimes with 24 hour resolution, then you would have to store AM/PM of some sort, which seems ugly to me.  So better go with military time.

Comment: ok that is fine but if i want to get only last 7 days records in the above query than can i use (SELECT DATE('now', '-7 day'))  ?

Comment: @Achin This is fairly different requirement from your original question.  You might want to consider opening a new one.

Comment: @Achin Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634542/sqlite-select-for-last-7-days

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from ATTENDANCE where c_date between 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd';
```

Instead of using c_TIME,use c_date field.

You can change the date format in the query accordingly to retrieve data between two specific times.

**Sqlite supports following formats:**

```
YYYY-MM-DD

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS

HH:MM

HH:MM:SS

HH:MM:SS.SSS

now

DDDDDDDDDD
```

See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)